# Oracle multicolumn index more columns or more indexes is better

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, indexing

When consider an multicolumns index in oracle, is that good to put more columns into an index than fewer columns. i.e I have a table with more than 20 columns, option A is create index_1a with col_1, col_2, col_3 and index_1b with col_1, col_4, col_5. may be add more index_1c with col_1, col_2, col_4
option B is create index_b with col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5

I have many queries search with different col combine,

- sometimes col_1 and col_2
- sometimes col_1 and col_4
- sometimes col_1 and col_2 and col_4

What should I do? Could you guys explain more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle implements skip-scan index operations, which are explained [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/index-skip-scanning).

For this reason, it is probably sufficient to have a single index on `(col_1, col_2, col_4)` or `(col_1, col_4, col_2)`.  You should test to see if the performance is sufficient for your purposes, but there is a good chance that a single index will satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle usually does not combine multiple indexes (assuming that the question is related to b*tree indexes, and not to bitmap indexes) - most of the time the optimizer will use only the most fitting index. In your example the first question is how selective the conditions are: if col_1 is very selective then maybe an index just on col_1 is sufficient. If only the combination of conditions provides a good selectivity then it could be necessary to create multiple indexes - and in this case you could end with (col_1, col_2, col_4) and (col_1, col_4) in your example. If there is only the index (col_1, col_2, col_4) for your second example query I would expect the optimizer to use only col_1 as access predicate and col_4 as filter predicate. Of course the addition of multiple indexes comes with the cost of increased work for the maintenance of the indexes when DML occurs.

With bitmap indexes the optimizer is able to combine them, but this index type is usually used only in data warehouses since it brings massive locking problems for concurrent DML.